# Curve Sketching True and False Check Please

Tags: calculus

If $ƒ′(x) < 0$ when $x < c$ then $ƒ(x)$ is decreasing when $x < c$.

F

The function $ƒ(x) = x^3 – 3x + 2$ is increasing on the interval $-1 < x < 1$.

F

If $ƒ'(c) < 0$ then $ƒ(x)$ is decreasing and the graph of $ƒ(x)$ is concave down when $x = c$.

T

A local extreme point of a polynomial function $ƒ(x)$ can only occur when $ƒ′(x) = 0$.

F

If $ƒ′(x) > 0$ when $x < c$ and $ƒ′(x) < 0$ when $x > c$, then $ƒ(x)$ has a maximum value when $x = c$.

T

If $ƒ′(x)$ has a minimum value at $x = c$, then the graph of $ƒ(x)$ has a point of inflection at $x = c$.

F

If $ƒ′(c) > 0$ and $ƒ″(c) > 0$, then $ƒ(x)$ is increasing and the graph is concave up when $x = c$.

F

If $ƒ′(c) = 0$ then $ƒ(x)$ must have a local extreme point at $x = c$.

F

The graph of $ƒ(x)$ has an inflection point at $x = c$ so $ƒ′(x)$ has a maximum or minimum value at $x = c$.

F

$ƒ′(x)$ is increasing when $x < c$ and decreasing when $x > c$ so the graph of $ƒ(x)$ has an inflection point at $x = c$.

T

Are my solutions correct? Thank you for your feedback and corrections.